# install R package requiring dll

Tags: r

I am looking at [this package](https://github.com/profyliu/gepR). I managed to install it like this:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("profyliu/gepR")
```

This package also requires a dll, which I downloaded. I think I can put this dll into my working directory but could it also be placed into the folder of the package and the [R file](https://github.com/profyliu/gepR/blob/master/R/gepR.R) would pick it up automatically (the R file linked to in github is also in my local package folder)?

Thanks and sorry about my ignorance.

Comment: I recommend raising an issue on the Github as this package does not seem to have a large community and maintainer will be in a much better place to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can. Look at function [`gep_load_dll`](https://github.com/profyliu/gepR/blob/master/R/gepR.R#L3) from [`gepR.R`](https://github.com/profyliu/gepR/blob/master/R/gepR.R)

```r
#' Load gepR.dll
#' @param dll_file the path and name of the dll file to be loaded.
gep_load_dll <- function(dll_file = "gepR.dll"){
  dyn.load(dll_file)
}
```

I think you just have to change the variable for this function such that it is the path to the dll file. To me it seems that the package does not care where you put it.

So just put the file into the directory you want, call this function with the path to the file and you should be fine. Particularely, when we also consider the example from the [demo](http://yliu.eng.wayne.edu/research/gepR_demo_A.html), where we find this code

```r
gep_load_dll()  # Load the gepR.dll from the default location
gepmod <- gep_train(y = train_y, x = train_x, maxiter = 1000, goal=0.95, nthreads = 10)
```

The comment seems to suggest that you can put it anywhere you like as long as you overwrite the default location.

Please note that I have not tried it out myself because I'm not a windows user. If it works, please let us know.

Comment: thanks. yes, I gathered that. I can put it in my working directory or somewhere else. I thought there is a better "global" transparent way. Guess I can adopt gepR.R in the package folder and hardcode things there.

Comment: Great! What do you mean with transparent? The package let's you set it - in fact, I think you have to - each time you want to use the package. This is transparent, isn't it? What were you hoping for?

Comment: By transparent i meant baking it into the package. I guess I have to simply edit the R script.